# Hyperledger fabric peer container not starting logs Unable to connect with couchdb

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

**Docker logs peer0.org1.example.com**

```
2020-01-30 11:03:43.890 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.4.4
 Commit SHA: 7917a40
 Go version: go1.12.12
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.18
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2020-01-30 11:03:43.891 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
2020-01-30 11:03:43.891 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
2020-01-30 11:03:43.921 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 004 ledger provider Initialized
panic: Error initializing ledger provider: unable to connect to CouchDB, check the hostname and port: error unmarshalling json data: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.initialize(0xc0003045a0)


       /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:81 +0x78a
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.Initialize.func1()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:53 +0x2a
sync.(*Once).Do(0x26d0748, 0xc0003ed458)
        /opt/go/src/sync/once.go:44 +0xb3
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.Initialize(0xc0003045a0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:52 +0x55
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.serve(0x26d0668, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:181 +0x568
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.glob..func3(0x25c7240, 0x26d0668, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:126 +0xf1
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x25c7240, 0x26d0668, 0x0, 0x0, 0x25c7240, 0x26d0668)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762 +0x465
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x25c7960, 0xc0003edf60, 0x1, 0x1)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852 +0x2ec
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800
main.main()
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:53 +0x41f
```

`Couchdb` container is up and running.

I have tried adding `GODEBUG=netdns=go` in d`ocker-compose.yml`, but no luck.

I am using `fabric 1.4.4` on centos7 server.

I am struggling from weeks on this but nothing is working.

Code docker-compose.yml

```
     #
# Copyright IBM Corp All Rights Reserved
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#
version: '2'

networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/4239aa0dcd76daeeb8ba0cda701851d14504d31aad1b2ddddbac6a57365e497c_sk
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.example.com
    networks:
      - basic

  orderer.example.com:
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 7050:7050
    volumes:
        - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
        - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
    networks:
      - basic

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=info
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
      # # bridge network as the peers
      # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
      - GODEBUG=netdns=go
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: peer node start
    # command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
        - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - couchdb
    networks:
      - basic

  couchdb:  
    container_name: couchdb
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 5984:5984
    networks:
      - basic

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=info
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
      - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    networks:
        - basic
#    depends_on:
      #- orderer.example.com
      #- peer0.org1.example.com
      #- couchdb
```

Comment: Can you share the snippets from your compose files as well? It will help to debug the issue.

Comment: @MrudavShukla I have added the snapshot of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a proxy interfering with your networking. The key is this message

```
panic: Error initializing ledger provider: unable to connect to CouchDB, check the hostname and port: error unmarshalling json data: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

When the peer tries to connect to what it thinks is the couchdb network, it actually is going to a proxy which is returning an HTML response of some sort.

Comment: yes, I am working behind a proxy. I have added no_proxy for docker in  ~/.docker/config.json as 
"noProxy": "localhost,127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,*.example.com,*.*.example.com"

and in bash_profile as well. Where else should i update it.

Comment: never had the scenario of being behind a proxy, but maybe you should change the couchdb setup so that it's url is `couchdb.org1.example.com` in line with the peer using it

Comment: Thanks @david_k. Your suggestions worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NitishGupta can you indicate me in more detail how have you solved this issue? I have the same.

Comment: @david_k change the url where? at docker-compose-couch you can only define the ports

Comment: Changed couchdb0 to couchdb0.example.com in docker-compose files under depends sections

Comment: Need to update docker-compose-couch.yaml like this

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    environment:
      CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb3.example.com:5984
 
    depends_on:
      - couchdb3.example.com